# Updating the PATH of Teamcity Agent on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, teamcity-8.0

I have a TeamCity 8 agent running on Ubuntu.

Scripts that run within its context in TeamCity aren't aware of rvm so I want to amend its path.

So in buildAgent.properties I want to set

`env.PATH=%PATH%:/home/build/.rvm/bin`

and have the machines path expanded and then rvm appended.

That doesn't appear to work... should it? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work, but you are missing the "env." in front of the PATH in the right side of the assignment. Should be like this:

```
env.PATH=%env.PATH%:/home/build/.rvm/bin
```